# Reverse a line in sed?

Tags: sed

```
 echo 1234 |   sed '
       /\n/ !G
       s/\(.\)\(.*\n\)/&\2\1/
       //D
       s/.//
     '
```

I'm unable to comprehend the above `sed` code.

my understanding is:

```
PATTERN SPACE=1234
first operation /\n/ !G ---> 1234\n(if \n is  not found it is appended at th end)
                s/\(.\)\(.*\n\)/&\2\1/ ----> 1234\n234\n1
                //D ----> \n234\n1(deletes upto newline and commands
                                   from the beginning are applied to the 
                                   existing pattern space)
PATTERN SPACE=\n234\n1
second operation /\n/ !G ---> skipped since  \n234\n1 has newline now
                 s/\(.\)\(.*\n\)/&\2\1/ ----> \n234\n1234\n
                 //D ----> \n234\n1234\n
```

It seems I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: You can write it a little more legibly and efficiently as `sed -e 'G;:1' -e 's/\(.\)\(.*\n\)/\2\1/;t1' -e 's/.//'`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a loop in this code that get's confusing to see. This bit:

```
   s/\(.\)\(.*\n\)/&\2\1/
   //D
```

Keeps looping, shifting the characters `234\n1` to `34\n21` until we're left with `\n4321`, where it then drops out of the loop.

The description by catonmat is spot on so I'm including it here: [37. Reverse a line (emulates "rev" Unix command).](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/sed-one-liners-explained-part-one/).

*excerpt*

> The first line `"/\n/ !G"` appends a newline to the end of the pattern space if there was none.
>
> The second line `"s/\(.\)\(.*\n\)/&\2\1/"` is a simple `s///` expression which groups the first character as `\1` and all the others as `\2`. Then it replaces the whole matched string with `"&\2\1"`, where `"&"` is the whole matched text (`"\1\2"`). For example, if the input string is "1234" then after the `s///` expression, it becomes `"1234\n234\n1"`.
>
> The third line is `"//D"`. This statement is the key in this one-liner. An empty pattern `//` matches the last existing regex, so it's exactly the same as: `/\(.\)\(.*\n\)/D`. The "D" command deletes from the start of the input till the first newline and then resumes editing with first command in script. It creates a loop. As long as `/\(.\)\(.*\n\)/` is satisfied, sed will resume all previous operations. After several loops, the text in the pattern space becomes `"\n4321"`. Then `/\(.\)\(.*\n\)/` fails and sed goes to the next command.
>
> The fourth line `"s/.//"` removes the first character in the pattern space which is the newline char. The contents in pattern space becomes `"4321"` -- reverse of `"1234"`.
>
> There you have it, a line has been reversed.